# In GNU tar, what does the 'y' operand do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu, tar

So I'm making a point to learn more about linux. Specifically, I'm doing as much as possible from a shell terminal, and when I encounter a task that requires me to google something, I also give the man page a read so as to actually understand what I'm doing (rather than simply cut and pasting code from the internet into my console). I just now had need to expand a tarball, and as usual, I forgot the operands needed to expand them.

After reading the man page I figured out what the `x`, `v`, `f`, and `z` refer to. What does `y` do -- I'm not seeing it in the man page (if it matters, I'm on Ubuntu/precise). From this [website](http://www.wallpaperama.com/disp-post26.html), I can infer that it does basically what `z` does, only for `*.bz2` files. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU tar man page doesn't seem to have `-y`, but my BSD tar man page does:

```
 -y      (c mode only) Compress the resulting archive with bzip2(1).  In
         extract or list modes, this option is ignored.  Note that, unlike
         other tar implementations, this implementation recognizes bzip2
         compression automatically when reading archives.
```

Best guess: `y` in GNU tar is a compatibility option (since GNU tar usually uses the `j` option for bzip2 compression).

Comment: I don't have this option either, same as OP. I'm using man page `tar 1.23`

Comment: Yeah, I'm using BSD tar. Amended my answer to clarify that.

Comment: derp - I should've caught that j serves the function of y in GNU tar. thanks for the quick response!